# Parity signer seed phrase recovery using ledger and polkadot.js: Why with same phrase a different account address appears?

Tags: parity-wallet, polkadot

In the past I made a Polkadot-cold-wallet using an old phone and parity signer. I added DOT to this wallet.

Today I entered that same seed phrase into a ledger. Unfortunately a different address appeared. Polkadot JS does allow different derivation paths through entering:

account type: 0, 1, 2, etc
address index: 0, 1, 2, etc
Does anybody know what selection of 'account type' and 'address index' gives me access to wallet I originally created in Parity Signer? P.S. I used Parity Signer v4.5.